# How to enable query logging in Spring Data Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spring-data, google-cloud-datastore, spring-cloud

I used to set some variables (easily found on the Internet) in `application.properties` to enable query logging in a standard Hibernate/JPA SQL application, e.g.:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

How could I do the same when working with [Spring Data Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.1.0.RC2/single/spring-cloud-gcp.html#_spring_data_cloud_datastore)?

I'm particularly interested in what GQL statements my [Repository methods "by convention"](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.1.0.RC2/single/spring-cloud-gcp.html#_query_methods_by_convention_2) convert to (if they do) - to estimate traffic, cost, etc.